# Find the area between the natural log and a related curve.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, parametrization

Let $f(x)=\ln(x)$.

Let $L$ and $M$ be two lines tangent to $f$ at the points $(t,f(t))$ and $(t+1,f(t+1))$.

Let $g(x)$ be the function who's graph is all the points of intersection of $L$ and $M$ for every $t\in(0,\infty)$.

Find the area between $f$ and $g$ in terms of known constants.  That is, find $$\int_0^\infty g(x)-f(x) dx.$$

The decimal approximation is $0.3803307...$

Update: I derived the answer to be $\frac12 (\ln\pi+\ln2-\gamma)-\frac14$

It’s been a long time since I’ve looked at this problem so I’m just posting the answer I got for the record. Let me know if you’d like me to provide some details.

Comment: you already seem to have the answer. what's the question?

Comment: The problem is to find that value in a form that’s closed in terms of well known constants.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: what are $L$ and $M$? Any tangent lines or the tangent lines defined by the derivative of $f$?

Comment: I fixed that. Thanks for the clarification.